# .wav format not supported in android devices

Tags: android

Here is my sample project ,I want to develope sample drums app,that plays back eight sound files when eight separate buttons are pressed.Code is working fine, but tone is not clear, how to get the original tone? ,is there any mistake in my code?

DrumsActivity.java

```
public class DrumsActivity extends Activity
{
private AudioTrackSoundPlayer soundPlayer = null;
private ArrayList<View> buttons = null;
private boolean[] buttonStates = null;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    buttons = new ArrayList<View>();
    buttons = new ArrayList<View>();
    buttons.add(findViewById(R.id.c));
    buttons.add(findViewById(R.id.d));
    buttons.add(findViewById(R.id.f));
    buttons.add(findViewById(R.id.g));
    buttons.add(findViewById(R.id.c1));
    buttons.add(findViewById(R.id.d1));
    buttons.add(findViewById(R.id.f1));
    buttons.add(findViewById(R.id.g1));

    buttonStates = new boolean[buttons.size()];
    soundPlayer = new AudioTrackSoundPlayer(this);
}

@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event)
{
    boolean[] newButtonStates = new boolean[8];

    int action = event.getAction();
    boolean isDownAction = (action & 0x5) == 0x5 || action == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN || action == MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE;

    for (int touchIndex = 0; touchIndex < event.getPointerCount(); touchIndex++)
    {
        // find button for location
        int x = (int) event.getX(touchIndex);
        int y = (int) event.getY(touchIndex);

        for (int buttonIndex = 0; buttonIndex < buttons.size(); buttonIndex++)
        {
            View button = buttons.get(buttonIndex);
            int[] location = new int[2];
            button.getLocationOnScreen(location);
            int buttonX = location[0];
            int buttonY = location[1];

            Rect rect = new Rect(buttonX, buttonY, buttonX + button.getWidth(), buttonY + button.getHeight());
            if (rect.contains(x, y))
            {
                newButtonStates[buttonIndex] = isDownAction;
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    for (int index = 0; index < newButtonStates.length; index++)
    {
        if (buttonStates[index] != newButtonStates[index])
        {
            buttonStates[index] = newButtonStates[index];
            View button = buttons.get(index);
            toggleButtonSound(button, newButtonStates[index]);
        }
    }

    return true;
}

private void toggleButtonSound(View button, boolean down)
{
    String note = null;

    switch (button.getId())
    {
        case R.id.c:
            note = "crash";
            break;

        case R.id.d:
            note = "hithat";
            break;

        case R.id.f:
            note = "snare";
            break;

        case R.id.g:
            note = "giant";
            break;

        case R.id.c1:
            note = "c";
            break;

        case R.id.d1:
            note = "d";
            break;

        case R.id.f1:
            note = "f";
            break;

        case R.id.g1:
            note = "tom";
            break;
    }

    if (down)
    {
        if (!soundPlayer.isNotePlaying(note)) 
        {
            soundPlayer.playNote(note);
        }
    }
    else
    {
        soundPlayer.stopNote(note);
    }
}
```

}

AudioTrackSoundPlay.java

```
public class AudioTrackSoundPlayer

{
private HashMap<String, PlayThread> threadMap = null;
private Context context;

public AudioTrackSoundPlayer(Context context)
{
    this.context = context;
    threadMap = new HashMap<String, AudioTrackSoundPlayer.PlayThread>();
}
public void playNote(String note)
{
    if (!isNotePlaying(note))
    {
        PlayThread thread = new PlayThread(note);
        thread.start();
        threadMap.put(note, thread);
    }
}
public void stopNote(String note)
{
    PlayThread thread = threadMap.get(note);
    if (thread != null)
    {
        thread.requestStop();
        threadMap.remove(note);
    }
}
public boolean isNotePlaying(String note)
{
    return threadMap.containsKey(note);
}

private class PlayThread extends Thread
{
    String note;
    boolean stop = false;
    AudioTrack audioTrack = null;

    public PlayThread(String note)
    {
        super();
        this.note = note;
    }

    public void run()
    {
        try
        {
            String path = note + ".wav";

            AssetManager assetManager = context.getAssets();
            AssetFileDescriptor ad = assetManager.openFd(path);
            long fileSize = ad.getLength();
            int bufferSize = 4096;
            byte[] buffer = new byte[bufferSize];

            audioTrack = new AudioTrack(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, 22050, AudioFormat.CHANNEL_CONFIGURATION_MONO, AudioFormat.ENCODING_PCM_16BIT,bufferSize, AudioTrack.MODE_STREAM);
            //audioTrack = new AudioTrack(android.media.MediaPlayer);
            audioTrack.play();

            InputStream audioStream = null;

            int headerOffset = 0x2C;
            long bytesWritten = 0;
            int bytesRead = 0;

            while (!stop)
            {
                audioStream = assetManager.open(path);
                bytesWritten = 0;
                bytesRead = 0;
                audioStream.read(buffer, 0, headerOffset);
                while (!stop && bytesWritten < fileSize - headerOffset)
                {
                    bytesRead = audioStream.read(buffer, 0, bufferSize);
                    bytesWritten += audioTrack.write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
                }
            }

            audioTrack.stop();
            audioTrack.release();
        }
        catch (IOException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

    public synchronized void requestStop()
    {
        stop = true;
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Have you taken a look at http://developer.android.com/guide/appendix/media-formats.html?

Comment: Ya, In my application its not supporting the tone, is differs from original tone.

Comment: What other sample rates have you tried?

Comment: you mean media format?

Comment: No, I mean sample rates. On the page I cited (emphasis is my own), "8- and 16-bit linear PCM (**rates up to limit of hardware**). **Sampling rates** for raw PCM recordings at **8000**, **16000** and **44100** Hz." What is the second argument to `audioTrack = new AudioTrack(...)` for?

Comment: Have you figured it out?

Comment: No not able to find,because am new to this.

Comment: Google Android AudioTrack and tell me what argument number 2 says. Then look at your code. Then look at my comment.